# Autofit content into a fixed size TextBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I can find loads of examples for resizing a textbox to fit it's content, but not the other way around. I have a WinForm 'popup' that is a fized size and contains a wallpaper thumbnail and a textbox which will holds the wallpaper title. Sometimes, the title can be short, or so long it drops off the end of the form:

[image]
[image]

The form is populated with information passed from another method:

```
    this.BringToFront();
    this.txtWallpaperTitle.Text = title;
    this.lnkWallpaper.Text = "http://www.reddit.com/" + threadid;

    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Properties.Settings.Default.currentWallpaperFile);            
    this.imgWallpaper.BackgroundImage = img;
    this.imgWallpaper.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Currently the `TextBox` text sdize is set via the designer. Is there any way to auto-resize the text so that it fits into the `TextBox` control no matter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe handling `TextChanged` `Event` by this way or similarly could solve it.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != "".Trim())
    {
        int w = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Width;
        int h = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Height;
        int sizeContent = w * h;
        int sizeTb = (textBox1.Width * textBox1.Height);
        if (sizeContent < sizeTb)
        {
            while (sizeContent < sizeTb)
            {
                textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, textBox1.Font.SizeInPoints + 1);
                w = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Width;
                h = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Height;
                sizeContent = w * h;
            }
        }
        if (sizeContent >= sizeTb)
        {
            while (sizeContent >= sizeTb)
            {
                textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily, textBox1.Font.SizeInPoints - 1);
                w = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Width;
                h = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font).Height;
                sizeContent = w * h;
            }
        }
    }
}
```